# How to bring Bootstrap modal at clicked button position?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to bring **Bootstrap modal** at clicked button position? I'm working on an `Iframe` area on small device modal popup (appears on top of the page). We need to scroll top to see it — how to solve this issue

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2>Modal Example</h2>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your question is unclear need more information

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the behavior of the Bootstrap modal

```
position:fixed
```

to

```
position:absolute
```

> What is Default Behavior?
> Default Behavior means the same behavior as Modal
> Popup as you can see on the Twitter Bootstrap site by default.
> What is Changed Behavior?
> By default the modal popup's opening as position: fixed
> but I have changed it as position: absolute.